# Open url in external browser in electron and angular2

Tags: angular, electron

I am creating an app using **electron** and **angular2**. I want to provide a help link which I want to open in **external** (default) browser of the user. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In electron it's actually pretty straight forward to open any link in your default browser. You just need to import/require the *shell* module from electron.

```
import { shell } from 'electron';

shell.openExternal('https://example.com');
```

if your are not using ES6 just replace the import with `const { shell } = require('electron');`

Comment: angular2 is throwing error "Cannot find module 'electron'"

Comment: @MohammadShahid seems like Angular 2 overrides require/import. Just follow this guide and you should be good to go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37327006/2004682

Comment: How to open it in a specific browser, exaple chrome and not my default explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using nodejs and command line, something like this.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('start /max chrome.exe --incognito --app=' + url, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

In this case `url` will be what you want to open. And here i'm opening Chrome. But if you want to open the predeterminate brownser, just put something like this.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('start /max ' + url, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42512480/848556

I fixed it by using **ngx-electron**

thanks